# notifyDataSetChanged() blanks out recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an issue where notifyDataSetChanged() in a response call will blank out the recyclerview but if the Adapter is initiated manually with a onClick, the recyclerview works. I have tested that the List has the items inside before calling notifyDataSetChanged() so i'm not sure what's wrong here.

[Main Activity] This works but i have to manually click the bnQuery.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        apiInterface = API_client.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

        etCoin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCoin);
        bnQuery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnQuery);

        rcvMain = findViewById(R.id.rcvMain);


        getCoinData("2");
        //initRCV_Main();


        bnQuery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //getCoinData("2");
                initRCV_Main();

            }
        });
    }

    private void initRCV_Main() {

        rcvMainAdp = new rcvMainAdapter(cList);
        rcvMain.setAdapter(rcvMainAdp);
        rcvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    private void getCoinData(String coinLimit){

        Call<cInfoPack> call = apiInterface.doGetCoinData(coinLimit);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<cInfoPack>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<cInfoPack> call, Response<cInfoPack> response) {

                cInfoPack list = response.body();
                List<cData> listSorter = new ArrayList<>();
                listSorter.addAll(list.getData());
                Collections.sort(listSorter, new SortbyVolChg());

                cList.clear();
                cList = listSorter;

                System.out.println("list " + list.getData().get(0).getQuote());
                System.out.println("listSorter " + listSorter.get(0).getQuote());
                System.out.println("cList " + cList.get(0).getQuote());

                //rcvMainAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<cInfoPack> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("XXXX", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                call.cancel();
            }
        });

    }
```

[Main Activity] If i initiate the recyclerview during onCreate and use the notifyDataSetChanged() during getCoinData, I get a blank recycleview. system.out shows that the lists all contain information in them.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        apiInterface = API_client.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

        etCoin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCoin);
        bnQuery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnQuery);

        rcvMain = findViewById(R.id.rcvMain);


        getCoinData("2");
        initRCV_Main();


        bnQuery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //getCoinData("2");
                //initRCV_Main();

            }
        });
    }

    private void initRCV_Main() {

        rcvMainAdp = new rcvMainAdapter(cList);
        rcvMain.setAdapter(rcvMainAdp);
        rcvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    private void getCoinData(String coinLimit){

        Call<cInfoPack> call = apiInterface.doGetCoinData(coinLimit);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<cInfoPack>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<cInfoPack> call, Response<cInfoPack> response) {

                cInfoPack list = response.body();
                List<cData> listSorter = new ArrayList<>();
                listSorter.addAll(list.getData());
                Collections.sort(listSorter, new SortbyVolChg());

                cList.clear();
                cList = listSorter;

                System.out.println("list " + list.getData().get(0).getQuote());
                System.out.println("listSorter " + listSorter.get(0).getQuote());
                System.out.println("cList " + cList.get(0).getQuote());

                rcvMainAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<cInfoPack> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("XXXX", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                call.cancel();
            }
        });

    }
```

[Adapter]

```
public class rcvMainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<rcvMainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<cData> idxCoin;

    //ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    rcvMainAdapter(List<cData> data) {this.idxCoin = data;}
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rcv_main,parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        cData cdata = idxCoin.get(position);

        TextView tvSym = holder.tvSymbol;
        tvSym.setText(cdata.getSymbol());

        TextView tvQuo = holder.tvQuote;
        BigDecimal tvQuote_BD = new BigDecimal(cdata.getQuote().getuSD().getPrice().toString());
        tvQuote_BD.setScale(6, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        tvQuo.setText(tvQuote_BD.toString());

        TextView tvV24 = holder.tvVolume24;
        BigDecimal tvVolume24_BD = new BigDecimal(cdata.getQuote().getuSD().getVolume24h().toString());
        BigInteger tvVolume24_BI = tvVolume24_BD.toBigInteger();
        tvV24.setText(tvVolume24_BI.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return idxCoin.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvSymbol, tvQuote, tvVolume24;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvSymbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSymbol);
            tvQuote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuote);
            tvVolume24 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVolume24);

            //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

    }

    /*
    public interface ItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    }

     */

}
```

PS: apologies for the rubbish coding as this is self taught and modifying some codes found online.

Comment: your variables names are really quite confusing, hopefully they mean more to you and nobody else has to review this code in future :) not sure why stuff is prefixed with `c`. from what i can see, i don't see how you're changing the content of your adapter. you don't have something like `adapter.items = foo` and then a notify statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this in response.

```
   cList.clear();
```

Add This line in response

```
rcvMainAdp.setdata(listSorter);
```

In rcvMainAdp Adapter, Create a Method setdata()

```
    public void setdata(ArrayList<cData> data) {
   
       this.idxCoin = data;
       
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Excellent! this solves it. But why doesnt the line "rcvMainAdapter(List<cData> data) {this.idxCoin = data;}" work in the adapter? Sorry i'm still trying to figure out how the whole flow works.

Comment: If this solve it accept the answer.   The problem was  cList = listSorter;  in response.
Please study "=" in Java. You will understand.  This is assignment. You are clearing clist of adapter and then you are not updating the list in adapter. instead you are assigning in activity.   listSorder and clist point to same list in memory but the list inside adapter is old one which is empty that why no data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! that clarifies my understanding of the work things work. yea it was working as it should before i introduced the listsorter method and did a couple of other things but not sure what caused it.

Comment: The problem is idxCoin was empty when you did this cList.clear(); .  you were not updating it.
you did this  cList = listSorter. and that was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Problem most likely is that when you call `initRCV_Main()` You set the adapter to the list as in `rcvMainAdp = new rcvMainAdapter(cList);` And when list is changed and you set it to adapter it functions.

But when you call `getCoinData()` and `rcvMainAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the end you never set the changed list to the adapter until you click `initRCV_Main()` again.

So maybe the fix is calling `rcvMainAdp = new rcvMainAdapter(cList)` and then
`rcvMainAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();`